# Passing parameters into SQL script via cron

Tags: mysql, shell, cron

I have a shell script which runs some sql as follows:

```
DB_USER="xxx"
DB_PASSWORD="yyy"

/usr/bin/mysql -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASSWORD < /home/xylar/tasks/users.sql
```

In the sql file I export the users into a txt file using:

```
SELECT
    'id',
    'name',
    'status'
UNION ALL SELECT a.* FROM(SELECT
    id,
    name,
    status
FROM
    users
)a

INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/YYYYMMDD_users_000INC.txt'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

I am running the script every month via a cron task:

```
0 0 1 * * /home/xylar/tasks/export.sh
```

There are two variables in the sql file, YYYMMDD and INC, is there a way to pass them in as variables?

- YYYYMMDD current date
- INC an incremental integer, each time the script is run this needs to be increased by 1

Comment: Just for personal interest: Why you need a date and increasing number if the script is only rune once per month? So the YYYYMM would be enough?

Comment: @bish the exports are sent to a client and this is the requested format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need current date in place of YYYYMMDD, you could get it from SQL script itself - by now() funtion.

For incremental number - you could also generate it yourself in SQL using AUTO_INCREMENT field of new table you have to create for this purpose.

But if you need pass in specific YYYYMMDD and INC, you have to "preprocess" original SQL before putting it to "mysql" cmd.  How to do it you ou could read [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files)